# Oracle SQL Trigger insert/update

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Ok so my question should be an easy one i think.
I am just learning Triggers, and I am trying to figure out a homework question.
I have three tables,
Movies (title, year, length, genre, studioName, producer) 
StarsIn (movieTitle, starName) 
MovieStar (name, address, gender, birthdate)

So basically i need to write a trigger for assuring that at all times, any star appearing in StarsIn also appears in MovieStar. I need to make the trigger for both insert and update events.

UPDATE:
Ok so i changed my statement a little but i still can't figure this out

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER movieTrigger
  AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON STARSIN
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN(new.STARNAME NOT IN(SELECT "NAME" FROM MOVIESTAR))
  BEGIN
INSERT INTO MOVIESTAR("NAME")
VALUES(new.STARNAME)
END;
```

Now I am getting the error

```
Error report:
ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here
02251. 00000 -  "subquery not allowed here"
*Cause:    Subquery is not allowed here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the subquery from the statement.
```

I just learned that oracle does not support a subquery in the when clause...
So i am trying to figure this out with limited knowledge. But if anyone has a clever way of doing this i would really like to know :-).

Thanks again

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a foreign key for this? There's no reason that this should ever be a trigger.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404667/oracle-trigger-insert-update

This link should help, I had a similar problem..

Comment: Just a side note: in your executable section (`BEGIN..END`) you need to refer to the columns using bind variable syntax, e.g. `VALUES(:new.STARNAME)`.

Answer (score 1):

You created a statement-level trigger. It will fire once for each insert or update statement. But a single insert or update statement can insert/update many rows in one go. Your code however needs a single row and assumes that only a single row is inserted or updated.

What you need are rowlevel triggers ("FOR EACH ROW") if you want to follow this path.

Answer (score 0):

Your `trigger` should be fired `before`(in this case) the `insert` of any `row` (currently it fires once for multiple rows inserted once)

I would recommend reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm

Its always better to use a foreign key constraint for ensuring that the value that appears in table `b` is present in table `a`, in this case there should be a `foreign key` in your table `StarsIn` for column `starName` referencing `name` in `MovieStar` table